# toggleFade the top of div only?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `<div>` that when I click on it it toggles another `<div>` right underneath it and when you click it again it goes away.

The problem is, there are input forms in the `<div>` that shows up and when I click **anywhere** in the `<div>` that appears it disappears again.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click").click(function(){
    $(".fade", this).fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="click">
  <div style="height:40px; width:900px; border-radius:5px; cursor:hand; cursor:pointer;">
     <img src="images/editloadout.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="fade"> </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can make it so that it toggles only when you click the editloadout.png `<img>`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `$(".click img")` instead of just `$(".click")` as your click selector and then modify the fadeToggle, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click img").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".fade").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please **class="fade"** div use outside of your **class-"click"** div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click img").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".fade").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

Changes **$(".click")** to **$(".click img")**